# Ambiguous column name after insert outer select

Tags: sqlite, ambiguous

My tables are Store(ID, Name), Orders(ID, StoreID), OrderItem(ID, Quantity, OrderID, ProductID).

From the below code, i've got the Orders.ID when product 1 outsells product 2.
Now i need to refer to the store ID and get the name of the store. I'm stuck here.

When I try to add SELECT * FROM the below code, I got error ambiguous column name: OrderID.

What should I do?

```
SELECT OrderID as OID
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM OrderItem as OI
    WHERE OI.ProductID = 1
) AS A,
(
    SELECT *
    FROM OrderItem as OI
    WHERE OI.ProductID = 2
) AS B
WHERE A.OrderID = B.OrderID AND A.Quantity > B.Quantity
```

Comment: If any of the answers helped you, mark it as an answer so that the question can be closed and other users can use this as reference! Wont take much of an effort from your end, would it?

Answer (score 0):

The join you performed provides two tables A and B, both of them having the column `OrderID`, hence the SQL engine couldn't interpret which of the columns to display, thereby giving you the error. What you need to do is as follows:

```
SELECT A.OrderID as OID
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM OrderItem as OI
    WHERE OI.ProductID = 1
) AS A,
(
    SELECT *
    FROM OrderItem as OI
    WHERE OI.ProductID = 2
) AS B
WHERE A.OrderID = B.OrderID AND A.Quantity > B.Quantity
```

Answer (score 0):

When the column used for a join has the same name in both tables, you can use the [USING clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#fromclause), which not only saves typing, but also removes the duplicate column from the result:

```
SELECT OrderID as OID
FROM
(
    SELECT *
    FROM OrderItem as OI
    WHERE OI.ProductID = 1
) AS A
JOIN
(
    SELECT *
    FROM OrderItem as OI
    WHERE OI.ProductID = 2
) AS B
USING (OrderID)
WHERE A.Quantity > B.Quantity;
```